# How to alter table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I converted a MySQL table to SQL Server but I'm getting the following error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 762
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ADD'.

My script:

```
ALTER TABLE [Appointments]
    ADD PRIMARY KEY ([Appointment_Id]),
    ADD KEY User_Id ([User_Id]),
    ADD KEY Status ([Appointment_Status]),
    ADD KEY Availability_Id ([Availability_Id]);
```

Comment: [`ALTER TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) does not work that way in T-SQL. Use `ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: [CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has everything you need... with valid syntax

Comment: Looks like you used your imagination instead of documentation. For the primary key you would use a constraint. What are those ADD KEYS ? Maybe you should explain your intent.

Comment: Even in MySQL use `ADD INDEX`, not `ADD KEY`. There are no "just keys" in a table. There's a primary key, candidate keys, surrogate keys. This has nothing to do with whether they are indexed or not.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I just converted MySQL table to SQL Server using some tools and it gave me like this. When I executed, it threw error.

Comment: @Knowledgebase that's because you used a quirky MySQL syntax for adding *indexes*. MySQL is notorious for its quirks, standard-breaking and undocumented behavior. *No* database is fully standards-compliant anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Can you please help me to convert this. I have heaps of this kind of table. If I get to know one then the rest I will try.

Comment: As I said, your intent is not clear. I gave you some code assuming your were trying to create Primary and Foreign keys. Indexes are created using Create Index syntax (it doesn't create and index automatically for foreign keys, but it does for primary keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to create a primary key on column Appointment_Id and likely other columns are part of the primary key???? (Do not look like foreign keys):

If all were meant to be part of primary key:

```
Alter Table Appointments 
   add constraint [MyAppointmentConstraint]
   on Appointments Primary Key (Appointment_Id, User_Id, Appointment_Status, Availability_Id);
```

Or if some were foreign keys:

```
Alter Table Appointments 
   add constraint [MyAppointmentConstraint]
   Primary Key (Appointment_Id)

Alter Table Appointments 
   add foreign key (User_Id) references Users (UserId);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The second one works for me.